# Retrieving list of secrets from azure keyvault in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve and print a list of secrets from an azure keyvault use the python sdk.

The following returns an paged.SecretItemPaged object:

```
from azure.keyvault import KeyVaultClient, KeyVaultAuthentication
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials


az_client_id = '*****'
az_secret = '*****'
az_tenant = '*****'
credentials = None


def auth_callback(server, resource, scope):
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=az_client_id,
        secret=az_secret,
        tenant=az_tenant,
        resource="https://vault.azure.net"
    )
    token = credentials.token
    return token['token_type'], token['access_token']


client = KeyVaultClient(KeyVaultAuthentication(auth_callback))

secrets = client.get_secrets('https://thevault.vault.azure.net/')

print('vault secrets:\n{}'.format(secrets))
```

e.g:

```
vault secrets:
<azure.keyvault.models.secret_item_paged.SecretItemPaged object at 0x7fc494c78b38>
```

I'm not sure how to handle this object. The documentation isn't giving me any hints, unless I've just missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SecretItemPaged page is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) object, meaning you can use it inside a for loop directly if you want:

```
for item in secrets:
    print_my_secret(item)
```

or change it to a list

```
secrets_as_list = list(secrets)
```

No magic here, it's just the iterator protocol of Python. You can also use `next`, and catch the `StopIteration` exception, etc.

Looking at the `get_secrets` method, [the doc tells you what kind if object it conveys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-keyvault/azure.keyvault.key_vault_client.keyvaultclient?view=azure-python#get-secrets):

[image]

And `SecretItem` is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-keyvault/azure.keyvault.v7_0.models.secret_item_py3.secretitem?view=azure-python-previous&viewFallbackFrom=azure-python).

Note that all SDK object have a `as_dict` method if you prefer to work on it as a dict, and not an object with attributes.

Do NOT use the `current_page` attribute. The iterator protocol implementation hides for you fetching multiple pages from Azure if you have more secrets than the default JSON can handle it. When doing `list(secrets)`, you might fetch 10 pages and do 10 calls to Azure, you don't know, you don't care :). `current_page` is the state of the last page. It is NOT the entire list of elements.

(I work at MS in this SDK team)

**Edit Dec/2020**

The answer is still valid, though the functionnality has moved into the [azure-keyvault-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-secrets/) package instead. Therefore, import are sligtly different, see [sample for reading secrets from KeyVault](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/samples/hello_world.py).

Comment: Ok, i have it working. Thanks for the detailed response, I understand what's going on now.

Comment: FYI, the documentation for the `SecretItem` class has apparently moved, the current version is here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-keyvault/azure.keyvault.v7_0.models.secret_item_py3.secretitem?view=azure-python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-keyvault/azure.keyvault.v7_0.models.secret_item_py3.secretitem?view=azure-python)

Comment: Ok. I think the functionality now has been included to the latest SecretClient to use `list_properties_of_secrets ` as show in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-keyvault-secrets/azure.keyvault.secrets.secretclient?view=azure-python#azure-keyvault-secrets-secretclient-list-properties-of-secrets